# Kivy Layout square Stacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I was making a program similiar to exel.
And then I ran into a issue.
StackLayout stacks good, but because the size of inputs is static it leave a blank space in some cases.

I try to do like `size=(self.width/5, self.height/5)`.
If someone saw how exel look now that there are more inputs of the screen this is why I use ScrollLayout and I want only 5 inputs in one row(user can change it in display settings(I will do it then creating rest of UI))

Here is what I had tried for now.
main.py:

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class EditorGrid(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        size = dp(self.width / 5)
        print(size)
        for i in range(0, 100):
            b = TextInput(text=str(i + 1), size_hint=(None, None), size=(dp(size), dp(size)))
            self.add_widget(b)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.size = dp(self.width/5)
        print(self.size)
        pass


class pxApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pxApp().run()
```

kivy file:

```
Scrolling:

<Scrolling@ScrollView>
    do_scroll_x: True
    do_scroll_y: True
    EditorGrid:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height

<EditorGrid>:
```

There is next problem that in **init** window size is 100x100.

Comment: Your `kivy` file and your `main.py` are identical?

Comment: @John Anderson Sorry, wrong thing copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [setters](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.setter) in binding under kv script. If you want to apply it in python, you could use a binding function for each button.

```
b = TextInput(.......) #omit size_hint and size attributes
#the following function is called every time EditorGrid(self) size_hint changes when the function is bind
#The function could be defined in a outer scope.
#Look at kivy callback functions to better understand the syntax
binding_function = lambda ins, *a: setattr(ins, 'size_hint', tuple((dim/5 for dim in self.size_hint))
b.bind(size_hint=binding_function)
```

Comment: I quite don't understand how to implement that... I am beginer with this and I have completly no idea what are talking about.

Comment: Lookup python [lambda functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp), [setattr](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/setattr.html) and kivy's [bind](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind). These are vital functions for python and kivy respectively. If confused on the ```setter``` method, look at examples and try to apply to your instance.

Comment: So where I put that?

Comment: The 1st line is analagous to your code. Replace your TextInput with my code's TextInput suggestions and the following code.

Comment: Is it right? It print "Invaild Syntax Error"
Link to code:
https://gist.github.com/comand100vip/65f4ebf4e65ab293d1a8c632e0924bda